# JSON url parsing issue with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, itunes

I have a requirement to parse **iTunes** url and display data. I have an issue when I'm parsing, can anyone who knows how to do it, parse below url in **jQuery ajax** or **js**?

I have tried a lot but getting error undefined.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
    var flickerAPI = "https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json";
    $.getJSON(flickerAPI, { format: "json" })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#your-tweet').append('<li>'+data);
        });
}
```

Comment: What is `data` ? Please log it and post the output

Comment: You may need to use a server-side proxy as I'd imagine your request is being blocked by the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: feed:object was out put

Comment: no i got data object but not going to parse in next step , got also data length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all name list with below code .

```
for(i=0;i<=10;i++) 

    { 

         var d1 = data.feed.entry[i]["im:name"].label;

        alert(d1)

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
flickerAPI = "https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json"; 
$.getJSON(flickerAPI,{ format: "json" }).done(function(data) 
{
    alert(data.feed.entry[0]["im:name"].label);
});
```

The fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/YGbx7/1/

Comment: How can someone give -2 to this answer, its perfectly right http://jsfiddle.net/YGbx7/

Comment: yes it's parse but i want to entry feed under im:name: {
label: "Ek Villain (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack)"
},

Comment: having issue in im:name: tag parsing isssue

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(){
  var flickerAPI = "https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json";
    $.getJSON(flickerAPI, { format: "json" })
        .done(function(data) {
         var d1 = data.feed.entry[0]["im:name"].label
         console.log(data)
         $('#your-tweet').append('<li>'+JSON.stringify(d1));
    });
```

}())

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xiqix/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the correct way:

```
var URL = 'PATH_TO_YOUR_SERVER';

$.get(URL, {}, function(response){
    // Here 'response' is the JSON response

},'json'); // Tells to jQuery that the response is a JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all to for reply

Here i have done with below code .

```
(function(){
```

var flickerAPI = "https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json";

$.getJSON(flickerAPI, { format: "json" })

.done(function(data)

{

for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
     {
      var d1 = data.feed.entry[i]["im:name"].label

$('#your-tweet').append('

'+JSON.stringify(d1));

}

});
}())

http://jsbin.com/seyuwele/1/edit